# Quickblox error: You are not connected and not authorized

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I know this question has been asked multiple time but none of them solved my problem.

**Error Domain=com.quickblox.chat Code=401 "Password not verified"** 
actually I have tried this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSLog(@"bdsfbd %@",chatuserobj.fullName);
    NSLog(@"Chat Id %lu",(unsigned long)chatuserobj.ID);
    NSLog(@"Current User %@",[QBSession currentSession].currentUser);

    QBUUser *currentUserr = [QBUUser user];
    currentUserr.ID = appDelegate.loginUserId;
    currentUserr.password = appDelegate.loginUserPassword;

    // connect to Chat
    [QBRequest logInWithUserLogin:appDelegate.loginUser password:appDelegate.loginUserPassword successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user)
    {
        chatDialog = [[QBChatDialog alloc] initWithDialogID:NULL type:QBChatDialogTypePrivate];
        chatDialog.occupantIDs = @[@(chatuserobj.ID)];
        [QBRequest createDialog:chatDialog successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBChatDialog *createdDialog)
         {
             NSLog(@"Created Dialog  %@",createdDialog);
         } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response)
         {
             NSLog(@"Error  %@",response);
         }];            
    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

    }];

    [[QBChat instance] connectWithUser:chatuserobj completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error)
     {
         NSLog(@"USer is Connected %@",error.description);
         [self startChat];
     }];

    [QBSettings setKeepAliveInterval:30];
    [QBSettings setAutoReconnectEnabled:YES];
}
```

and this

```
-(void)startChat
{
    [[QBChat instance] addDelegate:self];
    QBChatMessage *message = [QBChatMessage message];
    [message setText:@"Hey there"];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    params[@"save_to_history"] = @YES;
    [message setCustomParameters:params];
    [chatDialog sendMessage:message completionBlock:^(NSError * _Nullable error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Completed: %@",error.description);
    }];
}
```

I don't know where I am wrong. So point out my mistake.

**EDIT: again in did load**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // connect to Chat


    [[QBChat instance] connectWithUser:currentUserr completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error)
     {
         NSLog(@"USer is Connected %@",error.description);
     }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
        {
            [self chat];
        });
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
                   {
                       [self startChat];
                   });
}
```

chat is method for creating dialog for private group or one to one connection

```
-(void)chat
{
    chatDialog = [[QBChatDialog alloc] initWithDialogID:NULL type:QBChatDialogTypePrivate];

    chatDialog.occupantIDs = @[@(chatuserobj.ID)];

    [QBRequest createDialog:chatDialog successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBChatDialog *createdDialog) {

    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

    }];
}
```

and start chat actual communication occur

```
-(void)startChat
{
    [[QBChat instance] addDelegate:self];
    QBChatMessage *message = [QBChatMessage message];

    [message setText:@"Hey there"];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    params[@"save_to_history"] = @YES;

    [message setCustomParameters:params];

    [chatDialog sendMessage:message completionBlock:^(NSError * _Nullable error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Completed: %@",error.description);

    }];
}
```

now this error occur
**UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = You are not connected to chat.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // connect to Chat


    [[QBChat instance] connectWithUser:currentUserr completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error)
     {
         NSLog(@"USer is Connected %@",error.description);

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)

                        {
                             [self chat];


                        });


         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)

                        {
                             [self startChat];


                        });

     }];



}
```

and same method of start chat and chat. it works well

Answer (score 1):

```
[[QBChat instance] connectWithUser:chatuserobj completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error)
     {
         NSLog(@"USer is Connected %@",error.description);    
     }];
```

**This method is used to connect yourself to the chat and not your opponents. Furthermore, in order to connect with this method your QBUUser instance must have valid password set as password property.
Basically you need to connect yourself to the chat and then just start creating dialogs and sending messages.**

Comment: when i use to connect myself then no error occur. but when i sent message then again this occur You are not connected to chat. here you can see my code